# How to reference the text in a cell in vba

Tags: vba

What i am about to ask may have already been asked before but i couldn't find the relevant thread, most likely because i am not phrasing the search correctly.

What i want to do in vba is open a workbook in the same folder as the excel-workbook with the macro.

Currently i have referenced the exact location of the file:

```
wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Scorecard\E2E.xlsx")
```

The name of the excel file may not be the same in the future.

So what i want to do is have the user type in the name of the file in Sheet1!A1 cell and then use the text typed in the cell.

I tried using the following but that didnt work. Its throwing a Run-time error '76' path not found.

```
wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path\Range("A1"))
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation operator in VBA is &. Use it to connect strings together:

```
wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("A1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Scorecard" & "\"
 Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
 wkbSource = path & Name & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: Worksheet has no Value property. He wants the value of Sheet1!A1, so this should read `Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value`